# Using onComplete Event and Pages.xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an `"a4j:commandButton"` that runs some JavaScript on an `"onComplete"` event.
There is also an `"action"` that is calling a method.

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{Bean.Method()}"
onComplete="thisJavaFunction()">
```

I am using pages.xml in Seam to change to a separate page when that method is called.

```
<page view-id="/webpages/page1.XML">
    <navigation from-action="#{Bean.Method()}">
        <redirect view-id="/webpages/page2.XML"/>
</page>
```

Problem:

I want `"thisJavaFunction()"` in the onComplete method to be called when page2 is loaded.
However because it is a separate page, the onComplete event does not occur.

I could use an onLoad event in the body of the page2, but I would rather not use this because page2 uses a template that other pages use (e.g page1), this means that when other pages are called then the onLoad event is called.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you please amend what language/platform this is in? Pure Javascript it is not.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an ASP.NET web component?

Comment: Or is it this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_Seam